# Between and within scatter matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, scatter

Can someone help me to create a matlab code for these 2 matrixes?

[this are the formulas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AX60H.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should consider formatting your answer correctly, the code you posted seems to be a math formula in latex, rather than actual code, which makes it very hard to read. Check  [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76902/how-can-i-write-math-formula-in-a-post) post for suggestion on how to fix the issue. Also you should post some code you already tried (and eventually didn't work) to show you put some effort in your problem before posting it here. Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
w = 0;

for i = 1:k
    for j = 1:N(i)
        x_diff = x(i,j) - mean(x(i,:));
        w = w + (x_diff * x_diff^T);
    end
end

b = 0;

for i = 1:k
    x_diff = mean(x(i,:)) - mean(x);
    b = b + (N(i) * x_diff * x_diff^T);
end
```

Comment: Assuming x(i,i:) is a column vector, W and B are matrices, sums of outer products, while your code computes scalars, sums of inner products.